# Double nested if-statement in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I feel I must edit my entire post and paste my real code here so you guys can see what I mean.

So, depending if the email is empty or if it's incorrectly formated, I want a message to be displayed in the div. However, only the first if-statement is evaluated; the second one isn't. Here are the two functions:

```
function val_email() {
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var pattern = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+@([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+\.([a-zA-Z])+([a-zA-Z])+/;
    var isValid = pattern.test(email);

    if (email != null && isValid == false) {
        return false;
    }else if (email != null && isValid == true) {
        return true;
    }
}

function form_validate() {
var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
var log_in_pw = document.getElementById("password").value;

var sign_in = document.getElementById("validate_sign_in");

if (email == "") {
    sign_in.innerHTML = "email is missing";
    return false;
}else if (val_email() == false) {
    sign_in.innerHTML = "incorrect e-mail format";
}
```

Please check the else-if. If the email is not valid, the string "incorrect..." should be produced.

Comment: What does "get stuck" mean? What does it do, what exactly do you want it to do instead?

Comment: Are you saying that if you have a function in the `else-if` it does not work? or just the nested `if` is not working? also you might want to check `if(!email || email === '')` instead of just comparing with empty string.

Comment: You should call your function with brackets. `my_func() == false`

Comment: The nested if-statement in the else-if doesn't get evaluated. If I have several else if-statements and one of them has an if-statement nested inside, the if-statement will stop evaluating there. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: Yes, I corrected the function where I call it with brackets. I did that in the real code, I just changed names really fast and forgot to add the brackets.

Comment: do you see any errors? `var my_pattern = (regex)` what is `(regex)` is it just an example or the actual code? Cause looking at the flow it seems that it should work if the control enters `else if`!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your logic is correct and it works fine for me, it might be the strongly type issue you are having.

Just change the else if to

```
else if(!val_email())
```

val_email() returns just true or false, so no need to use the '== false'.

Also a closing '}' is missing at the end of 2nd function in your code sample

Answer (score 1):

Your logic can be shortened here:

```
 var my_pattern = (regex);
 return email && my_pattern.test(email);
```

Answer (score 0):

try it like this:

```
function checkEmail(email){    

        if (email == "") {
                return false;
            }
            var my_pattern = (regex);
            var my_validate = my_pattern.test(email); 
            if (my_validate() == false) {
            return false;
            }
            return true;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in the following way

```
function validateEmail(email) {

    if(email && email.length > 0) {

        var my_pattern = (regex);
        var my_validate = my_pattern.test(email);

        if(my_validate) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Just check for positive situations and in all other cases return false.